# write the hibernate query to retrieve data with latest timestamp

Tags: sql, database, nhibernate

I want to retrieve unique data froma  table based on latest time stamp.

So If I have a table like this

```
guid  6   1/7/2010 9:55:29 PM
guid  6   1/5/2010 2:59:29 PM
guid  6   1/7/2010 2:55:29 PM
```

I need to write a query where I can query with no 6 and with latest timestamp in the same table.
So it should return me :

```
guid  6   1/7/2010 9:55:29 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this at the moment, but I think the HQL would look something like this:

```
from Item as i
where i.Number = 6
order by i.Date desc
```

Then when you create your Query object in code, you'll want to call `query.setMaxResults(1);`

As far as I know, there's no "select top" (or equivalent) in HQL.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I misread the question.  I think `query.setMaxResults(1);` is the proper way to do it then.